# Can I make separate site in umbraco with separate media for each

Tags: umbraco

I'm looking to host several differing sites with one umbraco installation. Is it possible to have separate users who administer separate sites with separate media.

Eg site blue.com can only access media uploaded by blue users 
site red.com can only access media uploaded by red users

It would also be nice if I could set up some common images that can be used by blue.com and red.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this really is a question for the http://our.umbraco.org forums. Secondly, there is already documentation and may discussions about how to do this in the forms of the same site.

But yes you can, however I would only suggest considering this is the sites were related otherwise I can imagine that they would become quite difficult to manage. For example, I would host two or more sites in a single Umbraco instance *only* if they were for the same client, shared similar templates, assests, functionality.

In the media library, you would create a root media folder for red.com and one for blue.com.
To filter media, you just need to ensure that the user accounts created for each site have access restricted to the appropriate root media folder for the relevant site.

Image picker data types can be created too to ensure that media selections are restricted to specific folders.